# Run shell script on the event of "possible SYN flooding"

Tags: linux, tcp, ddos, scalability, syn

I'd like to write a script that gets all the stats I need (top IPs, used memory, netstat, etc) at the time I got an SYN flooding, and write to a report file.

So, is it possible to trigger a script/command when the kernel alerts for "possible SYN flooding on port XXX" ?

> Jun 27 22:12:21 xxxx kernel: [xxxx.xxxx] possible SYN flooding on port
>   443. Sending cookies. Jun 27 22:13:22 xxxx kernel: [xxxx.xxxx] possible SYN flooding on port 443. Sending cookies. Jun 27 22:14:25
>   xxxx kernel: [xxxx.xxxx] possible SYN flooding on port 443. Sending
>   cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: yes!

But that depends a bit in the syslog daemon you're running.

Syslog-ng allows that with the [`program()`](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/administration-guide/71#TOPIC-956654) destination.

Rsyslog offers [`actions`](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/actions.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have succeeded in running a script on the event of SYN Flooding. I use "rsyslog". Very kind regards!